# Sending parameters from a hyperlinkfield box to next page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a datagridview that is populated by a datatable and I want to be able to pass the value of a cell to the next page when a user clicks on that cell. The value of that cell is then passed to a sql stored procedure. Can someone offer a way on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could populate a [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) variable on click or add a QueryString parameter to the hyperlink - however, please keep in mind that either of these could be altered by the end user (the QueryString parameter more easily than the session variable), so you've got to worry about SQL injection on the page that executes the stored procedure.

EDIT - assuming the code you provided for the column, you'd just have to add the value to the NavigateUrl of your HyperLinkField, with something like:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="OnCallStart" HeaderText='OncallStart" NavigateUrl="\website1\Default2.aspx?value=<%# HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("DataSourceField")) %>' SortExpression="OnCallStart" />
```

And process the value on your new page (Default2.aspx) using `Response.QueryString("value")`.

Comment: Ian, I have this code now <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="OnCallStart" HeaderText="OncallStart" DataNavigateUrlFields="SchedName,OncallStart"    
                    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="\website1\Default2.aspx?date={0:d}&amp;schedule={1}" 
                    SortExpression="OnCallStart"   /> and my link isnt showing up anymore for the OncallStart Field and the datatable on the default2.aspx page is not being filled. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are there any exceptions being thrown?  What happens if you change the DataNavigateUrlFormatString to something like "{0}", or just "\website1\Default2.aspx" - do you still have issues?  Also, considering mapping the direct link to the page you want by using tilde, like `~/website1/Default2.aspx`.

Comment: Ian, there is no exception being thrown and when I try to save my connection string, I see that it's "Custom" even though when I go through the wizard, I set the connection string correctly. I've copied the web.config file from where Visual Studio wants to save it to the root directory but that doesnt seem to fix the problem. When I go back to look at my datatable, the same "custom" connection string is there. Any idea as to why?

Comment: So what I've now done is completely start over again from scratch with the code I had saved. I removed the end of the urlformatstring, and the link is still not showing up on the page.

Comment: Where are you setting the connection string for the GridView's DataSource?  Debug your application and see where the DataSource.ConnectionString property is being set, and where it might change.

Comment: And you're sure the datasource has data for the OnCallStart field?

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would use QueryString, something like:

```
<asp:GridView... >
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
   <a href='nextPage.aspx?value=<%# HttpUtility.UrlEncode(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,  "ColumnName")) %>' ><%# Eval("TextField") %></a>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

And in the nextpage:

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) ...

   passedValue = Request.QueryString("value").ToString()

   DoSomethingWith(value)

End Sub
```

Comment: onof this is the code for the field in question: <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="OnCallStart" HeaderText="OncallStart" 
                    NavigateUrl="\website1\Default2.aspx" SortExpression="OnCallStart" /> where would I insert your code?

Comment: you have to turn it into a TemplateField, like this: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OncallStart" SortExpression="OnCallStart" ><ItemTemplate><a href='\website1\Default2.aspx?value=<%# HttpUtility.UrlEncode(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "OnCallStart")) %>'><%# Eval("OnCallStart") %></a></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>

Answer (score 0):

The three most popular that I have seen are:

- Query string
- Posting values to the next page
- Session State

You can read about all three in [this article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx)  As @Ian points out it will be easy for people to modify query string parameters so use them carefully.  If you are using Parameterized queries (as you should be) then SQL Injection will not be a problem.

Comment: Abe, I've read that page and don't understand how the value of what's clicked is passed between pages. I'm assuming that Session State is the way to go.